# how do I call a function to compute angles in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I want to generate `chemfig` code that instead of having fixed
angles allows for some modification of groups of figures in a consistent way.
So, I want to write things like the last line below,

```
\chemfig{
               O% 1
     =[:90,0.2]% 25
    -[:150,0.2]% 23
                  (
        =_[:90,0.2]% 24
                      (
            -[:\fangle{150},0.5in + .01\linewidth]% 29
```

but nothing works for `fangle`. For example, all variants of things like these fail,

```
\newcommand{\fangle}[1]{\FPeval{\sht}{#1 + 999}\FPeval{\ss}{round(\sht,0)}\pgfmathparse{\ss}\pgfmathresult}
```

While the output of fangle looks ok elsewhere, it never works within
`chemfig` although IIRC it would work if there was no 
parameter but that does not help much. The length changes seem like they may work however. Thanks.

Comment: While you can do a lot with macros, perhaps this task is best solved via scripting or programming. I.e. it's easier to define and set parameters as needed to impact on the groups. Finally you just generate and store Latex-code. // If you like to do it in an object oriented way, which I highly recommend, strive for PHP (command line), C++, Java and similar. But also PERL will still do a fine job here. // E.g. you can design Latex code as usual AND preprocess it for fine tuning of angles via a script.